# Rounding number in HTML while using Web API

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, webapi

i was in the process of making my webside when i came across a little cosmetic problem. Whem i divide two numbers inside of a .setHTML function i get a number with a long string of numbers which is not suprising to me. I was just wondering if is it possible to round that number to, let's say two decimal numbers. Thanks for help in advance.
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.14.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.14.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<style>
body {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
 }
 
#map { 
position: 
absolute; 
top: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
width: 100%; 
}

#tekst {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
padding-top: 35px;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}

#tytul { 
position:absolute; 
color: black;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: 15px;
background-color: white;
height: 100px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="tytul">
<div id="tekst">
Mapa szpitali i aptek w Polsce
</div>
</div>
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoia3J6eXN6dG9mMiIsImEiOiJjbGhlc2EwNTIwem1oM2RwY2RpemwzaGp4In0.x7xfNDAYaSEYTs8eOrE76w';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container ID
        // Choose from Mapbox's core styles, or make your own style with Mapbox Studio
        style: 'mapbox://styles/krzysztof2/clhesgvjn019x01pgbm9tbibx', // style URL
        center: [19.09293251378324, 52.12102552114246], // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: 5.95308191712759 // starting zoom
    });
    
    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.ScaleControl({
    maxWidth:400,unit:'metric'
    }),'top-right');
    
    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
    
    map.on('load', () => {
    map.on('click', '3D-extrusions', (e) => {
    new mapboxgl.Popup()
    .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
    .setHTML('Liczba szpitali to:<b> '+e.features[0].properties.hospitals+'</b></br>A liczba aptek to: <b>'+e.features[0].properties.pharmacies+'</b></br>Liczba aptek na jeden szpital to: <b>'+e.features[0].properties.pharmacies/e.features[0].properties.hospitals)
    .addTo(map);
    });
 

    map.on('mouseenter', '3D-extrusions', () => {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
 

    map.on('mouseleave', '3D-extrusions', () => {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
    });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What i want to change:
[Red arrow is pointng at the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xenRU.png)

I tried functions like maxLength from html and round() from js and many others but nothing is working unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method. You can pass it the number of digits you want appear after the decimal point.

```
const decimalNumber = (e.features[0].properties.pharmacies/e.features[0].properties.hospitals).toFixed(2);
```